# Old SQL files still lingering and in use

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I had 2 different databases that I deleted via Microsoft SQL Server Management.
So they can no longer be found in the program.
But their .ldf and .mdf files remain and annoyingly sqlserver.exe is still using them!

I have created and deleted databases many times and only these 2 still linger.

Can I tell MSQLServer to stop using them or delete them without having to restart sqlserver.exe?

These old files that shouldn't be there are actually taking up a lot of disk space.

Comment: Does `USE master; SELECT * FROM sys.master_files WHERE physical_name = '{FULL PATH TO FILE}';` (for example `'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SANDBOX\MSSQL\DATA\Sandbox.mdf'`) return anything? if yes, then the database you "deleted" hasn't been deleted (dropped). You'll need to `DROP` the database. If no, then SQL Server isn't using the file, and something else is.

Comment: ah yes, it is actually listed there!

Comment: but when I try drop it, it says it does not exist or you do not have permission :(

Comment: Then you don't have permission. Ask someone that does have permission to `DROP` the database.

Comment: I am logged on to the server hosting the SQL server, as the admin. It must be because it technically doesn't exist.

Comment: What would happen if I delete it from sys.master_files? Would that stop the file from being used or make things harder?

Comment: You can't hack the system tables (also, these are views). What is the ID for the database, as seen from sys.master_files? Does this exist in sys.databases?

Comment: The database_id I'm looking at is 14 and the other is 15.
That's odd... in sys.databases those database_id's are assigned to different databases (that do exist)!
Luckily though I might actually not need those databases either.
How would you get around that though, make it use a new mdf and ldf?

Comment: Get around what? What is your actual goal here? If you *think* you don't need the files, but *think* you need the database, then **one** of those statements isn't true. You can't have a database without the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can detach the database, which is using those files and then delete the files.

[More information about detach and attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-detach-and-attach-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

In this case, you dont need to restart the SQL Server.

**UPDATE**

Also, see which application is holding lock on the files. [Stackoverflow question on finding application holding lock on file](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows#117908)

Comment: I tried detatching it by database name but it says: does not exist. Supply a valid database name

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so `sqlserver.exe` should use those files. But i can help you to remove it permanently.
CREATE one database with existing files using below script. and the remove it using `drop database database_name` command.

```
Create database dbname 
On 
(   
Filename= 'path where you copied files',   
Filename ='path where you copied log'
)
For attach;
```

Comment: Just tried that but it says: Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".

Comment: Execute `select * from sys.master_files` and find your file in the list. If exists in list then the database is available, else check, is there another sql server instance running?